# htacces doesn't rewrite url correctly

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I made Ajax navigation that call pages from a `/pages` file in a div, and I've tried many things to remove the `.php` from my URLs but I can't find the solution.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```html
Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.php$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^pages/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?slug=$1
```

So everything works well but I can't change my URL: `www.mywebsite.com/about.php` to `www.mywebsite.com/about`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It should remove `.php` extension from the end of your URLs.